# Amazon s3 bucket, CORS issue, header origin

Tags: amazon-s3, header, cors, quasar

We are using an Amazon s3 bucket to store our files. On the frontend side, we have to do this one:

```
fetch('https://some-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/some-bucket/4575/some-image.png');
```

On the amazon s3 bucket configuration, we added cors configuration:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "HEAD"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}
```

]

The main problem here header origin. In some cases browser set header origin in some cases not.

Here example when all okay:

```
GET /some-bucket/4016/Elephant_Large_PNG_Clipart-1047.png HTTP/1.1
Host: some-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36
Origin: https://some-domain.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://some-domain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6
```

Here is a request which is failed because the origin header is missing.

```
GET /some-bucket/4608/469705261---Copy.jpeg HTTP/1.1
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
Accept: application/json, text/plain, /
Referer: https://some-domain.com/
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36
```

In the amazon docs, we could see - that origin header is required. No origin header, cors issue. Origin header send, cors works well.

We have one more important thing, we are using https://quasar.dev/ on frontend side.

We decided to create plain js without any frontend framework. Just for test. Simple html just with fetch. It works everywhere! It sent header origin.

We tested in:
Firefox - always all okay in all cases.
Chrome - issue exist.

At this point we are using workaround with nginx like a proxy server to amazon s3 bucket, but we  would like to use s3 bucket directly.

I am confusing. Please share your thouths, or maybe we are missing something. I will be appreaseate. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

We resolved the issue, [this article](https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/handle-images-cors-error-in-chrome) helped us. We add this one "?some-parameter=some-unique-text" it resolved problem. Browser cache issue.